# How to find the current date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need to get the current date but in this format:

```
<dd>/<mm>/<yyyy>
```

Is there any method that i can use? 
I only found different formats and things I can't use for now. 
For working with python.

Comment: See [`datetime.date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime 
d = datetime.datetime.today()
print (datetime.date.strftime(d, "%d/%m/%y"))
```

Comment: Please explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date
timeNow = str(datetime.now())
print(timeNow)
```